# Linear independence of reciprocals of logarithms

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I would like to ask whether there is a proof of the following statement:
Let $p$, $q$ be primes and $n$ positive integer coprime with $pq$. Then $\frac1{\log p}$, $\frac1{\log q}$ and $\frac1{\log n}$ are linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: A much stronger statement follows from Schanuel's conjecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_conjecture), namely that the logarithms of the primes are algebraically independent.

Comment: I think this is still an open question.